# What is the story of Mandodari after Ravana's death?

Tags: ramayana, mandodari

What is the life story of Mandodari after Ravana's death?

Comment: she entered her husbands pyre, as its custom of those day like madri did when pandu died.. below answer is interpolation as mandodari is know for pathivratha status, ranks higher than Sacchi wife of indra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably she [married](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandodari#Marriage_and_later_life) Vibhishan:

> After the death of Ravana, Rama advises Vibhishana to take Mandodari
> as his wife, even though he already has a wife. A theory suggests that
> Ravana's race may have had matrilineal families and thus, to restore
> order in the kingdom after Ravana's death, it was necessary for
> Vibhishana to marry the reigning queen to get the right to rule.
> Another theory suggests it may be a non-Aryan custom to marry the
> reigning queen. The marriage between Mandodari and Vibhishana is
> purely an "act of statesmanship", rather than a marriage based on
> their "mutual sexual interference". Mandodari may have agreed to marry
> Vibhishana, her younger brother-in-law, as this would lead the kingdom
> to prosperity and stability as allies of Rama's Ayodhya, and she would
> continue to have a say in governance. Another reason for the marriage
> is as an alternative to suicide for the widowed Mandodari, which is
> averted by Rama.

[image] [refer](http://www.sitachronicles.com/glossary-of-hindu-references)

> Some legends state that in order to prevent Mandodari from entering
> the funeral pyre after the death of Ravana, Rama requested Vibheeshana
> to marry her in order to enable him to rule Lanka wisely. [Refer](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/vedic-society/women-of-bharat/puranic/mandodari)

Comment: i also found the same in wikipedia but i don't think it happend in valmiki ramayana isn't it.

Comment: Wikipedia should be avoided to quote answers.

Comment: Another baseless folklore. Nowhere said in the Ramayana. That doesn't make sense at all. Wikipedia doesn't give citations for the claim. It speculates it is necessary to have the reigning queen as wife to rule which is *totally false*. King's wife becomes the queen not queen's husband becomes king. This rule is made up by that author only. If you canquote any authentic sources other than wikipedia or blogs, the claim can be believed.